# Ioc Ninject: add parameters other than interfaces to constructors

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

In my actual code i have a similar situation:

```
public Interface IPerformer
{
    void Perform_A(int id, string name);
    void Perform_B(int id, string name);
    void Perform_C(int id, string name);
}


public MyClass : IPerformer
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IManager _manager;

    public MyClass(IMapper mapper, IManager manager)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public void Perform_A(int id, string name)
    { 
        _manager.DoSomething_A(id, name);
    }

    public void Perform_B(int id, string name)
    {
        _manager.DoSomething_B(id, name);
    }

    public void Perform_C(int id, string name)
    {
        _manager.DoSomething_C(id, name);
    }
}
```

My IManager implementation works with methods that requires an int and a string.
I was forced to create an interface that, in all its methods signature, exposed these two parameters so the injected IManager object could work with.

This class will be then called in a web api whose constructor will have an IMapper and an IManager parameters (obviously automatically resolved).

What i wish to do is to remove all occurrences of id and name parameters and pass them into constructor, but Ninject doesn't allow me to do something like that:

```
public MyClass(IMapper mapper, IManager manager, int id, string name) { ... }
```

and then in the webapi controller:

```
public class PerformController : ApiController
{
    public PerformController(IMapper mapper, IManager manager, int id, string name)
    {
        ...
    }   
}
```

Definitely, i'd like my IPerformer interface sounded like:

```
public Interface IPerformer
{
    void Perform_A();
    void Perform_B();
    void Perform_C();
}
```

And the knowledge of my parameters Id and name was just of the IManager object.

Is it possible to work around?

Comment: I assume that ninject has a factory pattern where you can do something similar to Autofac's delegate factories http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html This allows you to inject a Function delegate that takes the id and name so that the dependent class can pass those in. The other dependencies are handled by the framework. Sorry, I have not found this in the ninject docs

Comment: @DennisKuypers, i see Autofac does what i need in the PAYOFF section. I'm trying to find something similar for ninject. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how to achieve this:

Use `ToConstructor` method:

```
kernel.Bind<IPerformer>()
.ToConstructor(c => new MyClass(c.Inject<IMapper>(), c.Inject<IManager>(), 1, "test"));
```

Or use one of overloads of `WithConstructorArgument` method:

```
kernel.Bind<IPerformer>().To<MyClass>()
.WithConstructorArgument("id", 1)
.WithConstructorArgument("name", "test");

kernel.Bind<IPerformer>().To<MyClass>()
.WithConstructorArgument(typeof(int), 1)
.WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), "test");
```

**Edit**

For passing of dynamic parameters create factory and inject this factory.

```
public interface IPerformerFactory
{
     IPerformer Create(int id, string name)
}

kernel.Bind<IPerformer>().To<MyClass>();
kernel.Bind<IPerformerFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Comment: How can i set these parameters dinamically? "1" and "test" are different for each case. I used .WithConstrucotorArgument when i used Ninject as Service Locator. Imagine "MyClass" as a Web Api controller. All the interfaces are injected automatically through the pipeline.

Comment: @MaxBertoli, not clear what you need, but maybe factory can help you.

Comment: please take a look to this link (referred to Autofac), this is what i want: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html#the-payoff

Comment: @MaxBertoli, ok, so as I said factory should help you. See the edit. More info here: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki